# How to search for debian packages with command line?

Tags: debian, package-management

I do know http://packages.debian.org/ provide the search facillity.

The **problem** is how could I search the packages with just command line?

Comment: +: to search installed packages use 'dpkg -S regex'.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `apt-cache search` command will return all packages that have `name` in the package name or description:

```
apt-cache search name
```

Once you have a package name, you can get more detailed information on the package using the `apt-cache show` and `apt-cache showpkg` commands.

```
apt-cache show package_name
apt-cache showpkg package_name
```

Comment: +: apt-cache search --names-only search only the package names.

Comment: +: 'apt-cache show package_name' display package metadata,e.g,version,name,source,arch,size and 'apt-cache showpkg package_name' mainly show the version,and the very detailed forwad/reverse dependencies.

Comment: `apt list package_name` is even easier; `apt search query_string` if you want to search for all instances of a given string in the package database.

Answer (score 3):

apt-cache search

Comment: +1 This is the one.  It'll search descriptions as well as names, and isn't as bloated (or as incorrect) as some of the other solutions mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

While both aptitude and apt-cache do the job well, there is a new kid on the block; axi-cache.

axi-cache works a lot like apt-cache, but on steroids. ;) It uses a sophisticated tool called xapian to build an index and then queries that index. It bundles something called http://wiki.debian.org/Debtags>debtags in with the index as well. Debtags allow you to create little tags that stick to deb packages. Suffice it to say that debtags are a powerful way to search for packages and tools to get stuff done.

For example, if you wanted a WebDAV client in Debian you could do this;

```
axi-cache search protocol::webdav
```

That search produces this on my machine;

```
axi-cache search protocol::webdav
14 results found.
Results 1-14:
100% gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs - GStreamer plugin for GnomeVFS
100% sitecopy - A program for managing a WWW site via FTP, DAV or HTTP
100% davfs2 - mount a WebDAV resource as a regular file system
100% blosxom - light, feature-packed weblog app with plugin extensibility
100% lighttpd-mod-webdav - WebDAV module for lighttpd
100% nd - small command line interface to WebDAV servers
100% cadaver - command-line WebDAV client
100% subversion-tools - Assorted tools related to Subversion
100% libapache2-svn - Subversion server modules for Apache
100% libcommons-vfs-java - Java API for accessing various filesystems
100% subversion - Advanced version control system
100% eldav - interface to the WebDAV servers for Emacs.
100% libhttp-dav-perl - WebDAV client library for Perl, and "dave" CLI client
100% fusedav - filesystem to mount WebDAV shares
More terms: webdav servers authoring versioning files subversion remote
More tags: network::client protocol::http role::program implemented-in::c interface::commandline protocol::ftp devel::rcs
```

As you can see a lot of tools show up which is quite handy if you're not really sure what you are looking for but you know for example the problem area you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Install aptitude, them it's just `aptitude search xyz` for a list of packages with xyz in their name or one-line description.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt list package_name
sudo apt search text_to_search_for_in_all_package_fields
```

Answer (score -1):

As root:

```
apt-get search <package name>
```

If you didn't know about this, it is usually a good idea to run:

```
command --help
```

to see how you can you use the command. that or look at the man pages using

```
man <command>
```

Comment: @Jonno_FTW:Actually,I heard and used this command the other day.But it gave me too many result.So I have thougth there were any other splendid command...

Comment: you could always pipe it through less - apt-cache search | less

Comment: @Jonno_FTW:tired the apt-get search,shell returns invalid option.tried man apt-get ,could not find search option.googled,found nothing about apt-get.it seems we could not use apt-get search to search for packages!

Comment: You don't need to be root to use `apt-cache search <part of package name>`. I don't know of an `apt-get search`, however. That returns an error.